# Using ASP.Net Web Databound Controls to create Jquery Sliders tickers type controls

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, servercontrols, databound

I am working on a B2B portal web app, where i need to display upcoming news , products and company info on regular interval (say as slideshows and tickers).

For example :

Scenario 1. I need to display the latest company(registered in this week) in a marquee style. Where companies will be pulled out from database.

Scenario 2: I have some products categorized as hot products, that will be displayed as slideshow on the home or somewhere else.

I know using Jquery and Static pages its possible. But i havent idea about how to do this with ASP.Net databaound controls like grid, repeaters, datalist etc. We are not in favour of purchasing third party controls, instead it will be a last resort for us.

Please help me through buil-in controls. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What about to implement some javascript function and call it periodically and put inside of it some AJAX query to get data?

Comment: Please guide some sample example or online reference.. It would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should decide whether you want to do with JQuery Widgets or ASP.NET controls (or third party ASP.NET controls like Telerik). Can you use both - yes you can, but you are only going to add more complexity to your app because ASP.NET controls don't know about your JQuery Widgets and you have to provide the glue to tied them both and keep them synched up. So if you decide to build everything in JQuery - convert your static html pages to .aspx pages then add additional serverside functionality to return the data. For AJAX behavior, you can use what is called Page Methods in ASP.NET or write seperate Script Services. You will make use of what is called a ScriptManager. That way you can keep your existing markup and rely on ASP.NET to provide you with Data. The other alternative is to convert everything to ASP.NET Controls - and rely on the builtin or third-party control suite to provide the functionality.